# React - Splitting large comment component into multiple components

Tags: reactjs

I have a large `Comment` component which works great but is fairly lengthy. I have recently added a report button to the UI which toggles a `reported` state which should then change the output of the comment (removing everything and displaying a reported message). Trying to write the if statement in the return method of the component made me realise that I should be splitting this component up (not to mention that I have found myself copy/pasting a lot of code between this `Comment` component and the very similar `Reply` component).

The comment has 3 main 'views' - the default view, the reported view and the 'my comment' view.

Whenever I have tried to split up components in the past I have found myself getting bogged down in the passing of multiple props to each component. I'm not sure whether I'm doing it wrong or whether it is just something I need to get used to. Any tips on the best way of splitting this component up would be appreciated.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import { replyToCommentService, deleteCommentService, reportCommentService } from '../../../services/CommentService';
import { likeService, removeLikeService } from '../../../services/LikeService';
import Reply from './Reply';
import Avatar from '../Avatars/Avatar';
import IconWithText from '../Icons/IconWithText';
import CommentForm from './CommentForm';
import Dropdown from '../Dropdowns/Dropdown';
import DropdownSection from '../Dropdowns/DropdownSection';

export default class Comment extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      replies: this.props.replies,
      showReply: false,
      reply: '',
      replyBtnDisabled: true,
      liked: this.props.liked,
      numberOfLikes: this.props.likes.length,
      moreActionsActive: false,
      reported: this.props.reported,
    };
  }

  handleInput = (reply) => {
    this.setState({ reply }, () => {
      this.fieldComplete();
    });
  }

  fieldComplete = () => {
    if (this.state.reply.length) {
      this.setState({ replyBtnDisabled: false });
    } else {
      this.setState({ replyBtnDisabled: true });
    }
  }

  toggleReply = () => {
    this.setState({ showReply: !this.state.showReply }, () => {
      if (this.state.showReply === true) {
        this.replyInput.focus();
      }
    });
  }

  postReply = () => {
    const data = { comment_id: this.props.id, comment_content: this.state.reply };
    replyToCommentService(data, this.postReplySuccess, this.error);
  }

  postReplySuccess = (res) => {
    this.setState({ replies: this.state.replies.concat(res.data) });
    this.toggleReply();
    this.handleInput('');
  }

  error = (res) => {
    console.log(res);
  }

  toggleLike = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = { model_id: this.props.id, model_type: 'comment' };
    if (this.state.liked) {
      removeLikeService(this.props.id, 'comment', this.removeLikeSuccess, this.error);
    } else {
      likeService(data, this.likeSuccess, this.error);
    }
  }

  likeSuccess = () => {
    this.toggleLikeState();
    this.setState({ numberOfLikes: this.state.numberOfLikes += 1 });
  }

  removeLikeSuccess = () => {
    this.toggleLikeState();
    this.setState({ numberOfLikes: this.state.numberOfLikes -= 1 });
  }

  toggleLikeState = () => {
    this.setState({ liked: !this.state.liked });
  }

  moreActionsClick = () => {
    this.setState({ moreActionsActive: !this.state.moreActionsActive });
  }

  deleteReply = (replyId) => {
    this.setState({ deletedReplyId: replyId });
    deleteCommentService(replyId, this.deleteReplySuccess, this.error);
  }

  deleteReplySuccess = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ replies: prevState.replies.filter(reply => reply.id !== this.state.deletedReplyId) }));
  }

  ifEnterPressed = (e) => {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.postReply();
    }
  }

  reportComment = () => {
    const data = { model_id: this.props.id, model_type: 'comment' };
    reportCommentService(data, this.reportCommentSuccess, this.error);
  }

  reportCommentSuccess = (res) => {
    console.log(res);
  }

  render() {
    let repliesList;
    if (this.state.replies.length) {
      repliesList = (this.state.replies.map((reply) => {
        const { id, owner_id, content, owner_image_url, owner_full_name, ago, likes, liked } = reply;
        return (
          <Reply
            key={id}
            id={id}
            authorId={owner_id}
            title={content}
            image={owner_image_url}
            authorName={owner_full_name}
            timeSinceComment={ago}
            likes={likes}
            liked={liked}
            newComment={this.newCommentId}
            deleteReply={this.deleteReply}
          />
        );
      }));
    }

    const commentClass = classNames('comment-container', {
      'my-comment': this.props.myComment,
      'comment-reported': this.state.reported,
    });

    let likeBtnText;
    const numberOfLikes = this.state.numberOfLikes;
    if (numberOfLikes > 0) {
      likeBtnText = `${numberOfLikes} Likes`;

      if (numberOfLikes === 1) {
        likeBtnText = `${numberOfLikes} Like`;
      }
    } else {
      likeBtnText = 'Like';
    }

    const likeBtnClass = classNames('like-btn', 'faux-btn', 'grey-link', 'h5', {
      liked: this.state.liked,
    });

    let likeIconFill;
    if (this.state.liked) {
      likeIconFill = 'green';
    } else {
      likeIconFill = 'grey';
    }

    return (
      <li className={commentClass}>
        <div className="comment">
          <Avatar image={this.props.image} />

          <div className="body">
            <div className="header">
              <a href={`/user/${this.props.authorId}`} target="_blank" className="username green-link fw-medium">{this.props.authorName}</a>
              <span className="h5 text-grey">{this.props.timeSinceComment}</span>

              <Dropdown
                size="S"
                position="right"
                onClick={this.moreActionsClick}
                active={this.state.moreActionsActive}
                handleClickOutside={this.moreActionsClick}
                disableOnClickOutside={!this.state.moreActionsActive}
              >
                <DropdownSection>
                  {this.props.myComment &&
                    <button className="faux-btn dropdown-link" onClick={() => this.props.deleteComment(this.props.id)}>Delete comment</button>
                  }
                </DropdownSection>
                <DropdownSection>
                  <button className="faux-btn dropdown-link" onClick={() => this.reportComment(this.props.id)}>Report as inappropriate</button>
                </DropdownSection>
              </Dropdown>
            </div>

            <div className="comment-text"><p>{this.props.title}</p></div>

            <div className="actions">
              <button onClick={this.toggleLike} className={likeBtnClass}>
                <IconWithText text={likeBtnText} iconName="thumb-up" iconSize="S" iconFill={likeIconFill} />
              </button>

              <button onClick={this.toggleReply} className="reply-btn faux-btn grey-link h5">
                <IconWithText text="Reply" iconName="reply" iconSize="S" iconFill="grey" />
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        {this.state.replies.length > 0 &&
          <div className="replies-container">
            <ul className="replies-list faux-list no-margin-list">
              {repliesList}
            </ul>
          </div>
        }

        {this.state.showReply &&
          <div className="reply-to-comment-form">
            <CommentForm
              commentContent={this.handleInput}
              postComment={(e) => { e.preventDefault(); this.postReply(); }}
              formDisabled={this.state.replyBtnDisabled}
              placeholder="Write a reply... press enter to submit"
              btnText="Reply"
              inputRef={(input) => { this.replyInput = input; }}
              handleKeyPress={this.ifEnterPressed}
            />
          </div>
        }
      </li>
    );
  }
}

Comment.propTypes = {
  id: PropTypes.number,
  authorId: PropTypes.number,
  title: PropTypes.string,
  image: PropTypes.string,
  authorName: PropTypes.string,
  timeSinceComment: PropTypes.string,
  likes: PropTypes.array,
  liked: PropTypes.bool,
  replies: PropTypes.array,
  myComment: PropTypes.bool,
  deleteComment: PropTypes.func,
  newCommentId: PropTypes.number,
  reported: PropTypes.bool,
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Well the general problem is where your state lives.

Currently you have your state in the component (and/or services), that makes splitting up the component somewhat tricky and not feeling so "natural".

The reason is that each natural sub component (for example a replies list, or a reply itself) requires pieces of that state and perhaps also needs to modify that state, that's then being done by the "property passing" and it can be tedious. Passing pieces of the state down to sub components and/or passing event callbacks down such as "upDateState" "showThis" "showThat".

This is sometimes what you want, you can then create a stateless components that only renders ui, a list of answers for example. If this is what you want then yes, you just have to get used to passing in props from parents.

The other answer to continue growing you application is modeling it by its state and the only way to do that (properly) is to abstract the application state away from the component. Creating a state that does not live inside of a component, a state that every component can access.

You might have guess what my suggestion is by now, have a look at Redux (or similar state management lib.) and you can easily cut out pieces (components) and attach them to the Redux global state and action. Once you get used to "never" keep application state in your components you wont go back. :)

PS!
This is perhaps not an answer but its to long for a comment. Just wanted to share my thoughts.